# WebApi custom model binding

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a class as below

```
class myClass{
  string name;
  MyCustomType value;
}
```

WebApi Contrller action method as:

```
public string AddStudent([FromBody] myClass model)
{
//code implementation;
}
```

Now how to set MyCustomType when AddStudent action is called. I tried writing a model binder but it tries to set whole model like myClass. What i want is to write a common binder that will bind value passed from http post body to MyCustomType.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the complete code below and steps to post data to "AddStudent" action method using fiddler. It gives the response as the value of the "CustomField" that belongs to "MyCustomType" class. Let me know if you run into any issues?

**Model:**

```
public class MyClass
    {
      public string name;
      public MyCustomType value;
    }


   public class MyCustomType
   {
      public string CustomField { get; set; }
   }
```

**Controller:**

```
     [HttpPost]
     public HttpResponseMessage AddStudent([FromBody]MyClass model) {

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(model.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "text/html")
        };

     }
```

**Fiddler Post Request:**

[image: Post the data using fiddler]

Comment: Thanks Sail for your reply... myCustomType is actually a property of myClass.. So when binding happens how do i set value in myCustomType  of class MyClass

Comment: Edited my answer above. Please check and let me know if it works for you.